# Date picker in views for Drupal 6

Tags: views

Is there any way one can display date pickers as filter for a drupal 6 view?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just use Date-Filter (node) and expose as Popup. I assume you have the Date module (6.x-2.9 in my case) and Date Popup module installed and set your Datepicker on admin/settings/date_popup...

In Views it probably won't work in the preview, but on the view itself it will.

Comment: what is the url for date_popup module?

Comment: It's bundled with the date module (http://drupal.org/project/date) and also requires the jQuery UI module (http://drupal.org/project/jquery_ui) for the Date Popups datepicker to work!

Comment: What about date fields that don't come from Nodes, Users or CCK?